# How to change a string value with comma (343,543) to int in a dataframe with Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science, data-analysis

I have a CVS file [IMDb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IMDb) list. The number of votes is written like *345,545*, and Python sees this like a string. I want to change this to a number value for using operations like <,+,% and I want to add those values in a new column.

```
def change_int(x):
    y = x.split(",")
    z = int(y[0] + y[1])
    return z

df["imdbVotes2"] = df.imdbVotes.apply(change_int(df["imdbVotes"]))
```

I tried to use a function like this.

I expect:

```
0    343,564    343564
1    676,565    676565
```

Comment: `import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO("""
   col1     col2
343,564    343564
676,565    676565"""), sep= '\s+', thousands=',')`

Comment: HI Uğur Fatih Çokuçkun! Welcome to StackOverflow. It seems like you're wanting to remove the comma from numbers e.g. turn `100,000` into `100000`

Comment: Also I assume you meant csv file, not cvs?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your function has a small problem. The `split` function returns a list of strings, but you can’t directly concatenate those strings. You need to join the string first and then convert the result to an integer.

```
def change_int(x):
  y = x.split(",")
  z = int("".join(y))
  return z
```

This function will now take an input string like `'345, 545'` and return a corresponding integer `345545`.

Comment: This can't work as is. This is Python.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try to remove the commas with replace function and then convert the result to an int.

```
def change_int(x):
   return int(x.replace(",", ""))
```

It also works with numbers with more than one comma like `1,234,432`

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("IMDB_Top250movies2_OMDB_Detailed.csv")

result = df

def change_int(vote):
    votes = vote.split(",")
    votes = int("".join(votes))
    return votes

df["imdbVotes2"] = df.imdbVotes.apply(change_int)

result = df[(df["imdbVotes2"] > 100000) & (df["imdbVotes2"] < 300000)].head()
print(result)
```

---

This is how I solved it. Thank you.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).